# How can I print parsetime in Cakephp production?

Tags: cakephp

I would like to have parsetime printed in the footer of a few of my sites, because I just like it, see it as no security threat, it's easy to see performance and many of the site's visitors are webmasters.

I noticed that migrating from my own PHP code to Cakephp resulted in a parsetime from 0.02ms to 400ms with some optimizations (SQL query caching). I used microtime, probably miscalculated my own parsetime.

How can I print parse time in production in my view? I can build my own system with calculating in micro-seconds, but I would figure this would be possible with Cakephp functions, despite me unable to find them using Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP [used to output the execution time](http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/720-adjust-webrootindexphp-so-that-ajax-responses-come-back-without-timestamp) in an HTML comment. app/webroot/index.php included the following code at the bottom:

```
if (Configure::read() > 0) {
    echo "<!-- " . round(getMicrotime() - $TIME_START, 4) . "s -->";
}
```

`$TIME_START` is still defined in app/cake/bootstrap.php.